# How do I evaluate xe^x/(e^x-1) with numerical stability in Python?

Tags: python, numerical-stability

How do I evaluate xe^x/(e^x-1) with numerical stability around zero and when x is very positive or negative?  I have access to all the usual mathematical functions in `numpy` and `scipy`.

Comment: Just found scipy.special.exprel, which would work.  I need to have my code work on theano or tensorflow as well, so a more basic solution would be better.

Comment: Frustratingly, `np.expm1` seems to give `nan` instead of `inf` for large inputs. That makes it harder to avoid things like `if` or `where`.

Comment: This seems to be a [platform-dependent bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6818), still open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def f(x):
  if abs(x) > 0.1: return x*exp(x)/(exp(x)-1)
  else: return 1/(1.-x/2.+x**2/6.-x**3/24.)
```

The expansion in the last line can be extended in the obvious fashion if more precision is required, and can be made faster by re-phrasing.  As it stands, it errs by as much as 1e-6.

Comment: There is a not so large value `z` such that for `x > z` the real value of the expression `x*exp(x)/(exp(x)-1)` is very close to `x`, whereas computing it straightforwardly will result in overflow and nan.

Comment: Good point, @Leon.  To handle this possibility, the cases of `x > 0.1` and `x < -0.1` should be handled separately.  If `x > 0.1`, return `x/(1-exp(-x))`; if `x < -0.1`, return `x*exp(x)/(exp(x)-1)`; and otherwise use the polynomial approximation.